# Reference in the foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach, pass-by-reference

Having the reference in the foreach, what does it mean and what the benefit?

For example:

```
foreach ($delivery as &$store) {
            $store = ClassName::FunctionName($store);
} 
unset($store);
```

I never really use reference when I do some coding in PHP.

Comment: Please take a look in the manual, it explains that (and the second) use of references with [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach). Also references in general (variable aliases) are explained in the manual as well: [References Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Comment: As if not reading the manual wasn't bad enough, you didn't even [bother to search SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+foreach+reference&submit=search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't pass by reference into the foreach loop, any changes and updates won't automatically be retained in the initial data structure after the loop has completed.

For example:

```
$test = array('cat'=>'meow','dog'=>'woof');

foreach($test as $a){
    $a='test';
}
print_r($test);
```

In this case, the array will still contain:

```
array('cat'=>'meow','dog'=>'woof');
```

However in this example using references:

```
$test=array('cat'=>'meow','dog'=>'woof');

foreach($test as &$a){
    $a='test';
}
var_dump($test);
```

...the array will contain:

```
array('cat'=>'test','dog'=>'test');
```